# Java: Checking for nulls!

Tags: java

Let's say a you throw in an augment to your java program (Dealing with strings).

Something like command Null or Command Null!

Other then using a try/catch, is there an easy way to deal values like Null! ?

Comment: What does "throw in an augment" mean?  What is "command null"?

Comment: I think he means argument and is asking for a way to process null-vaues. The only way that i know of is a "if (object == null)"

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your arguments are Strings anyway..so if someone calls "yourprogram_name null", then the args array will have index 0 set to the String "null"

Comment: @user494901: Not even from the comments I get any idea what this is all about. Write a code snippet and show what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you can check if the parameters are null before proceeding with your execution, which is quite the standard protocol. Also if you do not want the checks you can wrap your method logic in a try-catch block where you are catching a `RuntimeException`. That will take care of your null pointer exceptions.

Comment: For example: `public void myMethod(String arg) { try { //do something with arg} catch(RuntimeException re){//do something without arg}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString;

if (myString == null)
  // this will run
```

or in a function

```
void MyFunction(String myString) {
      if (myString == null)
         // this will run
   }
```

Comment: what if they specify: null! with an Exclamation mark

Comment: @user: You need to clarify your original question.  A lot.  Are you talking about `null` (i.e. a *null reference*), or `"null"` (i.e. a string)?

Comment: @user494901: there is no difference between an uninitialized non-primitive variable and a non-primitive variable that has been explicitly set to null.

Comment: I'm asking about null. ... I have been told I need to check for Null and Null!

Comment: Is it possible that the person telling you to check for `null` was just being emphatic?

Answer (score 0):

The strings passed into the main method of a Java program (unless invoked programmatically) will never be null.  They could be empty however.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if ( args[0].length() == 0 ) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

They also might not exist, in which case you need to make sure the array itself has elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if ( args[].length < 4 ) {
      //print usage
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not have control over static void main